# Try to use ICS style NumberPicker based on 2.1 SDK?

Tags: android, android-widget

I am developing an application based on Android 2.1, on one page of my application, there needs an numberpicker. we know that android 2.1 doesn't contain numberpicker control, so I write one.

I need to show my version of numberpicker on Android 2.1, but the ICS style numberpicker in Android 4.0, to achieve that aim, I used reflection, When in my code, I detected the current Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14, I reflect a numberpicker of the target platform, and add it to current view dynamically.

My question is I can reflect a numberpicker when I run my application on an Android 4.0 platform, but the numberpicker style doesnot appear to be ICS style, Why?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the patience you could probably back-port the [NumberPicker class](http://www.devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/android/core/java/android/widget/NumberPicker.java.shtml). That aside, why use reflection? If you set your target API to 15 this is all you need. In your `layout` folder declare your *alternative* number picker. In `layout-v11` (`NumberPicker` is available in API 11 Honeycomb or higher) declare `android.widget.NumberPicker`. Give each the same ID and in your Activity have something along these lines:

```
private NumberPicker mNumPicker;
private SomeView mOldNumPicker;

public void onCreate(...) {
    // Use NumberPicker
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
        mNumPicker = findViewById(R.id.numpicker);
    } else {
        mOldNumPicker = findViewById(R.id.numpicker);
    }
}
```

This was you do not need reflection and will not run into any crashes due to accessing non-existent APIs. From here on out you just check `if (mNumPicker == null)` and `if (mOldNumPicker == null)` and determine which methods to call based on that. There is also this example of a [Number Picker using Buttons and an EditText](http://gafurbabu.wordpress.com/2012/03/29/android-number-picker-dialog/).